# Can ISAPI dll for IIS be written in managed C++?

Tags: iis, managed-c++, isapi

Can ISAPI dll for IIS be written in managed C++ or does it have to be written in native C++ ?

Comment: Must be native C++. If you want to write in managed C++, then why not use C#?

Comment: For information about "Develop a Native C\C++ Module for IIS 7.0", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis